# Two drop-downs in a panel but want to enable the second one only when first drop-down's value is selected

Tags: java, wicket

Two dropdown choices are available. One enables & other is disable in starting. When the first dropdown is filled with its choice then only the second dropdown will be enabled. This should be done using select2choice abstract class or ChoiceProvider

```
private static class ValueEditor extends Select2Choice<String> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = SingleFiniteValueEditor.serialVersionUID;

    ValueEditor(String id, EditableSingleFiniteModel<?> model, ChoiceProvider<String> provider) {
        super(id, model.valueModel(), provider);
        setOutputMarkupId(true);
        getSettings().setDropdownAutoWidth(true);
        getSettings().setCloseOnSelect(true);
        getSettings().setPlaceholder("");
        getSettings().setAllowClear(!model.mandatory());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Wicket's examples: http://examples8x.wicket.apache.org/ajax/choice
The source code is at `Source code > ChoicePage` or [here](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/master/wicket-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/examples/ajax/builtin/ChoicePage.java)

Basically you need to start with

```
models.setEnabled(false);
```

and then enable it if `makes` has a value:

```
makes.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("change")
    {
        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target)
        {
            models.setEnabled(makes.getModelObject() != null);
            target.add(models);
        }
    });
```

You just need to adapt it to Select2 components.

Comment: There is no function named like "setEnabled()" in select2 wicket

Comment: Any Wicket Component has this method. Select2Choice must have it too.

Comment: code is already written using select2 in the wicket. My problem is this that I have two dropdowns and second's choices are dependent on the first dropdown. these things already are done. Now my task is don't let choose second dropdown's value till the first dropdown has its value.
So the solution I thought is to enable the second dropdown only after the first dropdown has its selected value.

Comment: And this is what I have suggested you. As far as the first dropdown has non-null model object the second dropdown will be enabled.

Comment: But I am not getting that method.

Comment: The example you have suggested to me, in this, you have clearly two objects i.e makes and models but in my scenario, I have only one model for both objects. You can refer to my code above.

Comment: The link you have shared is for DropdownChoice. Can u share the link using Select2choice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the if else statement by targetting the first drop down and when there is an input, the 2nd drop down activates. Here is an example:

```
  if (combobox1.equals("yourChoice"))
        {
            combobox2.enable();
        } else 
        {
            combobox2.disable();
        }
```